# How can I make a background panel from a form transpart/invisible in an XNA window?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, colors, xna-4.0

I have an XNA project that utilizes the Windows.Forms to create the GUI. Our GUI consists of a left panel and right panel. They both have a image laid over them(let's call them the panel images). Those images have buttons with images over them. Now the panel images don't completely cover the panel. Now what we want to do is make the panel invisible or transparent so you only see the panel images. In the picture below I circled what I want to be transparent/invisible. As you can see on the upper part of the project it already looks transparent but that is only because it blends in with the background on the XNA scene. On the bottom where the panel is over the ground you can see how the panel extends further than the panel images. So, does anyone know how I can make those parts invisible/transparent.

Alright, we've messed around with making the panel color Color.Transparent, magenta(XNA transparent color) and those attempts haven't worked. Any input/advice is welcome and much appreciated.

Here is the code that sets up the panel:

```
        this.pnlLeftSide.BackgroundImage = global::Referenceator_UI.Resources.LeftBar;
        this.pnlLeftSide.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
        this.pnlLeftSide.Controls.Add(this.btnScreenShot);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Controls.Add(this.btnScale);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Controls.Add(this.btnMove);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Controls.Add(this.btnRotate);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Controls.Add(this.btnSelect);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Name = "pnlLeftSide";
        this.pnlLeftSide.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
        this.pnlLeftSide.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        this.pnlLeftSide.BackColor = controlColor; //this what we want invisible/transparent
```

-Thank you stackoverflow community

[image: Example of my problem]

Comment: Why is your panel too big?  Make it smaller :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property of your panels. You can create necessary `Region` objects manually (by enumerating lines describing visible polygon) or use some method which converts image with transparency color key to `Region` (easily googled - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886968/how-do-i-convert-an-images-transparency-into-a-region for example).

Since geometry of your panels does not seem to be too complex, you can create `Region` manually following way:

```
using(var gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
{
    // Here goes series of AddLine() calls.
    // You must 
    // gp.AddLine(0, 0, leftPanel.Width, 0);
    // ...
    gp.CloseFigure();
    return new Region(gp);
}
```

Note that you'll get sharp edges with this method (even if it works). Consider rendering all that GUI using XNA.